# I made a website and haven't shared it yet, how am I getting visitors?

Tags: vs-web-site-project

I bought a domain name and set up my front page so that every unique ip address gets logged into the database. It's a simple site that shows coronavirus cases for each U.S. state and globally, if anyone tries to google it there's no chance of it showing up. I've got 30 unique visitors from Ohio, Canada, Portugal, etc. For another site I made for university project, my MySQL database was downloaded and held ransom (I used root/password for credentials). Could it be the same situation this time?

Answer (score 0):

When you put a website online, Google (and maybe some other search engines) will index it in few minutes/hours except if you have a `robots.txt` file who don't allow robots to index your website.

So if your website is on Google, you have visitors

Comment: My site has the word "covid" in it, there's no way it shows up in a google search because Google and other sites already dominate covid info.

Comment: it's change nothing, your website is on google.

You can check with this kind of search request: `site:yourwebsite.com`

Even if you are in the last page for the work covid, you will get trafic.

Comment: I don't get any results doing site: but can I assume that most of my visitors are crawlers/indexers from various search engines?

Comment: You have to check IP address for that (whois xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx). You will get the country and the owner. For Google bot you will have Google as owner of the IP address, a probably the same kind of information for a big part of search engines